# Crank-Nicolson method for the heat equation should preserve mass

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, heat-equation

I'm tried to solve numerically the following PDE (forget that an exact solution is known):

\begin{array}{l l}
    \partial_t \rho - \varepsilon^2 \Delta \rho &= 0 &\text{ on } (0, 1) \times (0,1) 
\\
\rho(0,x)&=\rho_0(x),&\;\forall x\in [0,1]\\
\partial_x\rho(0,t)&=\partial_x\rho(1,t)=0,&\;\forall t \in [0,1]
\end{array}

If $\rho$ is a solution, then it's mass is preserved, meaning $\int \rho(t,x)dx=\int \rho_0(x)dx = \text{const}$.

To solve it I implemented the Crank-Nicolson method for the temporal derivative and central finite differences for the spatial derivative
\begin{equation}
    \frac{\rho^{n+1}_i - \rho^n_i}{\Delta t} = \frac{\varepsilon^2}{2 (\Delta x)^2} \left[ \left( \rho^{n+1}_{i-1} -2\rho^{n+1}_i +\rho^{n+1}_{i+1} \right)
    + \left( \rho^{n}_{i-1} -2\rho^{n}_i +\rho^{n}_{i+1} \right) \right]
    \end{equation}

Here $\rho(t_n,x_i)=\rho_i^n$.
Which in matrix form is:

\begin{equation}
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1 & -1& 0&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&0\\
-\alpha & 1+2\alpha & -\alpha & \cdots&\cdots&\cdots &0\\
0 &-\alpha & 1+2\alpha & -\alpha & \cdots &\cdots&0\\
\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots\\
0 &\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&-\alpha & 1+2\alpha & -\alpha \\
0 &\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots& -1& 1\\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\rho_{0}^{n+1}\\
\vdots\\
\rho_{i}^{n+1}\\
\rho_{i+1}^{n+1}\\
\vdots\\
\rho_{M}^{n+1}\\
\end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
0 & 0& 0&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&0\\
\alpha & 1-2\alpha & \alpha & \cdots&\cdots&\cdots &0\\
0 &\alpha & 1-2\alpha & \alpha & \cdots &\cdots&0\\
\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots\\
0 &\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\alpha & 1-2\alpha & \alpha \\
0 &\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots& 0& 0\\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\rho_{0}^{n}\\
\vdots\\
\rho_{i}^{n}\\
\rho_{i+1}^{n}\\
\vdots\\
\rho_{M}^{n}\\
\end{array}
\right)
\end{equation}

When I use this method, I get a solution that doesn't preserve mass. However, this numerical scheme should preserve it. That is, it should we true that
$
m^n=\sum_i\rho_i^n
$
doesn't depend on n.

Anyone know what am I doing wrong? Maybe I didn't do the modeling properly?

Edit: For mass to be preserved, we need that when we add theirs rows we get the vector $(1,\ldots,1)$, this is because
$$
m(Ax)=m((<R_1,x>,\ldots,<R_n,x>))=\\
<\sum_i R_i,x>
$$
Where $R_i$ are the rows of $A$.

Comment: Have you tried to use a higher-order approximation for the boundary condition? If you implement these as $O(Δx^2)$, then also the mass conservation will be only up to errors of size $O(Δx^2)$, accumulating in time.

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann I don't have my computer with me now. When I get home I'll try do that. (I'm thinking symmetric difference: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference_quotient )

Comment: Yes, you can use the symmetric difference with ghost cells outside of the domain, or use the one-sided difference formulas of higher order.

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann I'm having trouble with that. What do you mean ghost cells? I don't think symmetric differences solves the problem.

Comment: If you want to apply the central difference quotient to the derivative boundary condition, you need the cell $ρ^n_{-1}$. It is artificial, virtual, not really there, a ghost. As that derivative is zero, you get automatically $ρ^n_{-1}=ρ^n_{1}$, which can then be applied to the PDE at $x=0$, and gets the ghost cell eliminated before it is really used. In less simple situations it might be of advantage to keep the ghost cells, and keep separate equations for the boundary conditions and the discretized PDE.

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann And I get the exact same thing I have. Which doesn't work. Also, using forward formulas (like the kind one gets from interpolation) don't work either. I mean, they surely converge, but the reduce the mass by a factor of $O(\alpha)=O(\Delta t/\Delta x^2)$.